# (angularJS) make ng-click open a link on an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

New to Angular, so sorry if this has been covered somewhere but it's hard for me to explain exactly what I want in succinct terms.

Currently I have an ng-repeat pulling data from a JSON object and making a list.

```
<li ng-click="openLink()" ng-repeat="location in locations">
  {{location.name}}
</li>
```

Each object has a key called "link" and that key has a property that is a url. I want the function openLink() to open the link associated with each object. I'm not sure how to go about this in the controller.

I know i can do

```
<li ng-click="openLink()" ng-repeat="location in locations">
  <a ng-href="{{location.link}}">{{location.name}}</a>
</li>
```

but i'd like to be able to do it with ng-click instead to keep the index.html cleaner. So what do I put in here to accomplish the same thing?

```
$scope.openLink = function() {

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url that you want to redirect to is a route in your angular app, you need to inject the $location service into the controller, then in your function, set the path property on $location.

```
<li ng-click="openLink(location)" ng-repeat="location in locations">
  {{location.name}}
</li>


$scope.openLink = function(location){
    $location.path(location.link);
}
```

If the location link is a complete url, you should inject the $window service into your controller, and change the openLink function to set $window.location.href.

```
$scope.openLink = function(location){
    $window.location.href = location.link;
}
```

Comment: This seems to just add /#/<the url> the the end of the current url.

Comment: Is location.link is a full url? or a place in the SPA?

Comment: Full url to another website. Sorry, should have clarified that.